# Why doesn't this loop execute 1000 times?

Tags: java

I expect the compiler to run the loop for 1000 times for each thread, but the output is 12 12 12 12. Why is this happening?

```
public class Runy implements Runnable {
    int x, y;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            synchronized (this) {
                x = 12;
                y = 12;
            }
        System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runy run = new Runy();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(run);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(run);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your loop `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` <- what's missing at the end here

Comment: Ayyyyyyyyyyy! I just now saw what @MadProgrammer was referring to.

Comment: Hint: The code did exactly what you told it to

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG Your edit modified the code so that the original context to the problem has been lost (but the execution is the same)

Comment: Be careful with your edits folks; the edit actually managed to obscure the actual problem here.

Comment: The loop *is* iterating 1000 times, but since each iteration does exactly the same thing (assign 12 to both fields), you wouldn't know it. Each thread then prints the two number once, so with 2 threads you get the number 4 times. What did you expect to happen? You didn't say.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with your `for-loop`...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    synchronized (this) {
        x = 12;
        y = 12;
    }
System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
```

which is the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    synchronized (this) {
        x = 12;
        y = 12;
    }
}
System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
```

which should now highlight the problem.  Essentially, without the `{...}` block, only the `synchornized` block is been executed by the loop, a 1000 times.

Something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    synchronized (this) {
        x = 12;
        y = 12;
    }
    System.out.print(x + " " + y + " ");
}
```

should provide you with 4000 `12`'s

Comment: Even the original version of the question had the `System.out.print` indented the same as the `for` loop, so why do you believe it was intended to be inside the loop? The question doesn't actually say that that was the intention.

Comment: @Andreas Because otherwise, why ask the question?  The OP wants to know why it "only prints" `12 12 12 12`, so that leads me to believe that they wanted the print statement to be executed 1000 times within the loop

Comment: @Andreas And after seeing, I don't care to remember how many questions, about why `if` and `loop`'s don't work as expected because of missing `{...}` you kind of just assume

Comment: Yeah, I know, and it's an obvious assumption, but it is nevertheless an assumption. OP might as well have intended to write `+= 12`, and expected the result to be 12000 or 24000 or something, but that's just another possibility. Question is unclear, and should be closed as such (MCVE). Given the indentation, I'm not sure your assumption is correct, but we'll never know unless OP tells us. *<end of my 2 cents>*

Comment: @Andreas Good point, have you cast your close vote?  This is just a community wiki entry, so no skin of my nose ;)

Comment: Yup, 2 votes: MCVE and Down. Oh, and up for answer, even though I think you jumped to assumptions. ;-)